# How can deserialize using Newtonsoft.Json?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How to read it using Newtonsoft.Json?

```
{
  "192.168.0.12": 
       {
         "Name":"12",
         "Mode":"STOP"
       },
  "192.168.0.13": 
       {
         "Name":"13",
         "Mode":"STOP"
       }
}
```

I am using this data class as below:

```
class Device{
    public string Name;
    public string Mode;
}

Dictionary<string, Device> devices;
```

So, I tried this code to deserialize. But, I can't read value from JToken as dictionary.

```
JObject JDevices = JObject.Parse(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer));
foreach (JProperty property in JDevices.Properties())
{
    string name = property.Name;
    JToken value = property.Value;
    // to read Device.Name and Device.Mode
}
```

Comment: "_But, I can't._" is not a problem description. What exactly is the observed behavior of your code, what precisely can you tell about your problem? Note that if you iterate over the properties of your root Json object in your foreach loop, the values of those properties are themselves json objects (JObject instances). You will then either deserialize those JObjects into Device objects, or iterate again over the properties of those JObjects to get their properties+values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic object `var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);`

Code to convert to Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Device> devices = new Dictionary<string, Device>();
string json = "{\"192.168.0.12\": {\"Name\":\"12\",\"Mode\":\"STOP\"},\"192.168.0.13\": {\"Name\":\"13\",\"Mode\":\"STOP\"}}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
foreach (var item in result)
{

         var name = item.Name;
         evices.Add(item.Name.ToString(), new Device {Name = item.Value.Name.ToString(), Mode = item.Value.Mode.ToString()});

 }
```

Comment: Great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, no need to use dynamic.

```
var json = "{
  "192.168.0.12": 
       {
         "Name":"12",
         "Mode":"STOP"
       },
  "192.168.0.13": 
       {
         "Name":"13",
         "Mode":"STOP"
       }
}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Device>>(json);

foreach (var device in result.Values)
{
    var name = device.Name;
    var mode = device.Mode;
}
```